# Kendo Dropdown list: number of items to be listed when expanded

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

Kendo dropdown list by default shows 6 items when expanded (clicked on down arrow). How can we increase the number of items to be displayed?

Need to show at least 15 items instead of 6. Also need to change the height of list items so that more items can be shown.

Tried changing the height, but it increased the height of dropdown list itself instead of the slider that pops out when clicked.

Thanks!!!

Comment: How did you increased the `height` ? Using [parameter `height`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/height)  should work. Check this out: https://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/uZIvEWEP